# Numbers - Conditional Sum

Tags: numbers

How should I write the conditional `SUMIF` if I want to `SUM` values in `column C` where `column B` is `IP`?

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Ok, so it's something like this

```
SUMIF(B2:B37,"=IP",C2:C37)
```

Where B is the text column to test,`=IP` is the test condition, C are the values to sum.